# use awk to match rows for each column

Tags: bash, awk

How can awk be used to find values that match in row 2 for each column?

I would like to take in a tab limited file and for each column if any row below row 2 matches what is in row 2, print field with "match".

transforming this tab delimited file:

```css
header1 | header2 | header3
1       | 1       | B
--------+---------+----------
3       | 1       | A
2       | A       | B
1       | B       | 1
```

To this:

```css
header1 | header2 | header3
1       | 1       | B
--------+---------+----------
3       | 1 match | A
2       | A       | B match
1 match | B       | 1
```

Comment: Does your data actually look like that, with the `--+--`, or are there just tab characters between each field? @anubhava because it's not a `1`, I guess.

Comment: The match needed in column 1 is `1`.   The match needed in column 2 is again `1`, and the match needed in column 3 is `B`.  Each column needs to be taken independently.

Comment: The data is only tab delimited.  I was trying to make it clear by adding `--+--`, but its not.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pedantically, with `GNU Awk 4.1.1`:

```
awk -f so.awk so.txt
header1 header2 header3
1       1       B
3       1*      A
2       A       B*
1*      B       1
```

with `so.awk`:

```
{
    if(1 == NR) {
        print $0;
    } else if(2 == NR) {
        for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
            answers[i]=$i;
        }
        print $0;
    } else {
        for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
            field = $i;
            if(answers[i]==$i) {
                field = field "*" # a match
            }
            printf("%s\t",field);
        }
        printf("%s", RS);
    }
}
```

and `so.txt` as a tab delimited data file:

```
header1 header2 header3
1       1       B
3       1       A
2       A       B
1       B       1
```

This isn't homework, right...?

Comment: Cool -- you're welcome. If you're satisfied happy with this answer, don't forget to up-vote it and select it by clicking the check mark. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would go for something like this:

```
$ cat file
header1 header2 header3
1       1       B
3       1       A
2       A       B
1       B       1
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR == 2 { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) a[i] = $i }
    NR > 2 { for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if ($i == a[i]) $i = $i " match" }1' file
header1 header2 header3
1       1       B
3       1 match A
2       A       B match
1 match B       1
```

On the second line, populate the array `a` with the contents of each field. On subsequent lines, add "match" when they match the corresponding value in the array. The `1` at the end is a common shorthand causing each line to be printed. Setting the output field separator `OFS` to a tab character preserves the format of the data.